# Angular: How can private input parameters of a constructor be accessible in other class methods?

Tags: angular, typescript

Consider the following code:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onLoadServer(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['/servers']);
  }
}
```

The `router` field in the constructor is a variable private to the constructor. It should not be accessible to any other method in the class. How can we then access it in the `loadServer` method?

Edit: In most OOP languages, only **fields** marked as private are accessible in other class fields, not **local variables** of methods

Comment: the private here makes it private to the class.  so this. will work, but only within the class.  it also will not work from the template during an AOT build

Comment: The private annotation in the constructor is a sugar to make this a private member field of the class. If you do not want it to be a member, do not use the annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is shorthand for below code.

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  private router: Router;
  constructor(router: Router) { 
    this.router = router;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onLoadServer(id: number) {
    this.router.navigate(['/servers']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems like you are coming form pure OOPs (c#,JAVA), background.

If you add DI in constructor with private modifier then the Type Script will understand that you are going to use this variable in entire class. it's a short form of creating private variable in class label and initializing with in constructor with constructor param.

Following two codes will exactly the same.
1.

```
    private service:BasicService;
  constructor(service:BasicService ){
    this.service =service;
  }
```

2.

```
    constructor(private service:BasicService ){
  }
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

A private field declared inside a constructor is not accessible only inside this constructor but inside all your class.

In your case, you can check the dependency injection doc [here](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection) and especially the "Services that need other services" part.